# Unable to retrieve wchar_t* from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, string-conversion

I have been trying to call an API from DLL like below:

```
 [DllImport(@"TELCompress.dll", EntryPoint = "TELMonDecode", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int TELMonDecode(ref bool a, ref bool b, byte[] ab, System.IntPtr pDestBuf, int j, int byteCount);
```

Call from C# code

```
int returnval = TELMonDecode(ref a, ref b, bytes, destPnt, k, bytesRec);
```

C++ code in the DLL

```
__declspec(dllexport) int TELMonDecode(bool *bUnicode, bool *bCompress, BYTE *pSourceBuf, wchar_t* pDestBuf, int pDestBufSize,int byteCount)

{
 ...
    CString decodedMsg = _T("<Empty>");
    int erc = DecodeByteStream(bUnicode, bCompress, pSourceBuf, &decodedMsg);

    ::MessageBox(NULL,L"Decoding byte done",L"Caption",0);
    pDestBuf = decodedMsg.GetBuffer();
    ::MessageBox(NULL,pDestBuf,L"Caption in TELMonDecode",0);
 ...
}
```

I have referred to many links here but still I am unable to figure out what wrong I am doing. 
Please guide.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help. Also see [mcve] because that seems to be missing.

Comment: The snippet is woefully incomplete, nobody can tell where `destPnt` came from.  Just fix the declaration, the argument type should be `StringBuilder` instead of IntPtr.  Do **not** skimp on checking `pDestBufSize`, the GC heap corruption you get when the builder's Capacity is too low is entirely too difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use **BSTR*** instead on wchar_t* and you should be able to use **ref String** at C# side.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. It was helpful.

Now the code works as below 
C# code

```
    [DllImport(@"TELCompress.dll", EntryPoint = "TELMonDecode", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int TELMonDecode(ref bool a, ref bool b, byte[] ab, ref String pDestBuf, int j, int byteCount);
... //Some code here
//Call to the C++ function 
 int returnval = TELMonDecode(ref a, ref b, bytes, ref receiveStr, k, bytesRec);
```

C++ code in the TELCompress.dll

```
__declspec(dllexport) int TELMonDecode(bool *bUnicode, bool *bCompress, BYTE *pSourceBuf, BSTR* pDestBuf, int pDestBufSize,int byteCount)
{
  CString decodedMsg = _T("<Empty>");
  //Code to copy data in decodedMsg 
  CComBSTR tempBstrString(decodedMsg.GetBuffer()); //test 
  tempBstrString.CopyTo(pDestBuf);
 .... //Some more code
return 0;
}
```

And it works, the string is seen in the C# code which was earlier showing an empty string.

Thanks a lot for all valuable feedback and comments. 
-Megha